# Can a Bard's Superior Inspiration be used on the initative roll that generated it?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard, initiative

I'm curious of the timing around the bard's level 20 Superior Inspiration.

Superior Inspiration simply states:

> At 20th level, when you roll initiative and have no uses of Bardic
> Inspiration left, you regain one use.

Bardic inspiration has many uses and to a level 14 Lore Bard, the can use it with Peerless Skill. Since initiative is an ability check and can use Peerless skill and the Superior Inspiration happens on the initiative roll, I was wondering if the Lore Bard could immediately use the bardic inspiration generated from Superior Inspiration?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, this timing works.

Superior Inspiration triggers *when* you roll initiative.

Peerless Skill says:

> Roll a Bardic Inspiration die and add the number rolled to your ability check. You can choose to do so after you roll the die for the ability check

As soon as (“*when*”) you roll the dice, you get a Bardic Inspiration die. This is before the time when you may choose to use Peerless Skill (which is specifically *after* you roll), so the die from Superior Inspiration is available to you.